# What do Args, api, extraOptions mean in RTK query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying my hands at RTK query(the pic is a ss of tutorial I was watching on the same topic), but I fail to understand what Args, api, extraoptions and tags do. I've read the documents but it ended up confusing me even more. Any easy explanation please?
Also, is RTK query worth it or should I just stick to axios for data fetching and then use toolkit as a global data manager? I've tried asyncthunk but RTK query feels lightweight as statuses like(isloading, error and etc) are included and needs no manual coding.

[image]

Comment: Not sure about `tags` (can't see it in the screenshot of code - please include code as formatted text in the question) but the others are the parameter names of the arrow function assigned to `baseQueryWithReauth`

Answer (score 0):

These are the arguments your `baseQuery` will be called with whenever a query is executed.

- `args` is the object that you return from the `query` function of your endpoint.
- `api` is an object that contains a lot of information about the query that is currently going on
- `extraOptions` is an extra property you can set on your `endpoint` and that will be passed through to the `baseQuery`.

As you are writing a wrapper around the `baseQuery` here, you don't have to interact *too* much with them - your own `baseQuery` is called with them and you just pass them on to the original `baseQuery`.

If you want to know what is really on all those, just `console.log` them or try autocomplete. You will probably end up using `api.dispatch`, but not too much else in most cases.